# firebase direct auth with email and password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

hi when I want to allow a player to log via a button i use this function

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

this is a good solution for the first login. but i want to permit to signin directly without click the login button. what is the best way to signin directly?  at moment i try to store an email and password or a token in the offline storage and i use the signinwithemailandpassword method. but is better if exist a simple firebase function

Answer (score 1):

If your launcher activity is your LoginActivity then add this to your code.

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is already signed in
                launchMainActivity();


            } else {
                // User is not yet signed in
            }
        }
    };

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

alternatively you could use this in your onCreate, onResume or onStart of your LoginActivity

```
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null){
  launchMainActivity();
}
```

Comment: i use the ionic framework in javascript. but the getCurrentUser save the user in the cache?

Comment: @DThink please *always* tag with the language that you're using. That saves people who might be able to help from wasting time coming up with code that doesn't apply to you.

Comment: The gist of this answer is the same for all platforms. For the web, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: yes very sorry. the topic can be closed, you solution is good. thanks to all!